# Dropdown menu with delay

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

When you hover the main menu items, the delay of the first item keeps the menu item open, while the mouse is already on the second menu item. See gif below.

How will I be able to fix this? Keeping the delay, but when another menu is open, hiding the menu item instantly.

The problem,
[image: img indicating problem]

structure of html (compressed for better view):

```html
<div>
  <ul class="menu_type_top">
    <li><a href="#">Hello</a><li/>
    <li><a href="#">hi</a>
    <ul> 
      <li><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hi</a></li>
    </ul>
    
    <li/>
    <li><a href="#">ok</a><li/>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Code in javascirpt to correct:

```js
$('ul.menu_type_top > li').on('mouseover', function(e){
  var ulObj = $(this).find("ul:first");
  console.log(ulObj);
  ulObj.show();
  var menu_height = ulObj[0].clientHeight + 300;
  $('ul.menu_type_top').css({ height: menu_height });//pokazanie podmenu bo warstwa jest w divie gdzie overflow: hidden
}).on('mouseout', function(e){
  setTimeout( function(){ ulObj.hide(); }, 2000);          
  $('ul.menu_type_top').css({ height: 40 });//powrót do normalnej wysokości menu
});


$('ul.menu_type_top li li').on('mouseover',function(e){
  $('ul:first',this).show();
}).on('mouseout',function(e){
  $('ul:first', this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use append(1000) with some delay values.Hope it will work!